# Build multi-project fat jars with sbt-assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, multi-project

I have multi-project with the main module called root, consumer and producer modules with dependencies which depend on the core module. The core modules hold configuration related classes. 
I would like to build 2 separate jars for consumer and producer with separate main classes with sbt-assembly. However, when  I try to build them individually like this `sbt consumer/assembly` or altogether by running `sbt assembly`I get such an error and sbt cannot compile the whole project:

```
[error] (consumer / update) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a module is not authorized to depend on itself: demotest#demotest_2.11;0.1
[error] (producer / update) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a module is not authorized to depend on itself: demotest#demotest_2.11;0.1
```

What should I change in dependencies to package the jars properly? And should I run them separately or together?

```
lazy val overrides = Seq("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.9.5")

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  name := "DemoTest",
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven",
  dependencyOverrides ++= overrides
)

lazy val assemblySettings = Seq(
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("org","aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "slf4j", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "neo4j", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "typesafe", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("net", "jpountz", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
    case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
    case x =>
      val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
      oldStrategy(x)
  }
)

lazy val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.1.0-M4",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.neo4j.driver" % "neo4j-java-driver" % "1.5.1",
  "com.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "4.1",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.3.5",
  "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "6.2.4"
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(consumer, producer)



lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )

lazy val consumer = (project in file("consumer"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies)
  .settings(
    mainClass in assembly := Some("consumer.SparkConsumer"),
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "demo_consumer.jar"
  ).dependsOn(core)

lazy val producer = (project in file("producer"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  ).settings(
  mainClass in assembly := Some("producer.KafkaCheckinsProducer"),
  assemblyJarName in assembly := "demo_producer.jar"
).dependsOn(core)
```

Comment: `commonSettings` and `commonDependencies` are in `core`, then also included into `producer` and `consumer`. Since these two depend on `core`, isn't it redundant? Have you tried to remove them from `producer` and `consumer`?

Comment: After I remove this I get another error: `(consumer / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: demotest#demotest_2.12;0.1: not found
(producer / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: demotest#demotest_2.12;0.1: not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  name := "DemoTest",  // should not be defined at this level!
)
```

This `name` should be defined for root:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(core, producer, consumer)
  .settings(
    name := "demotest"
  )
```

The sub-modules will have "core", "producer" and "consumer" as their own names, unless `name` is not overriden in their settings.

Please also note that in your example `.aggregate` does not include `core`, but it should indeed.